# How do I get Visual Studio Code to trust our self-signed proxy certificate?

Tags: openssl, visual-studio-code

Our corporate firewall/proxy is keeping VS Code from being able to install extensions because Code doesn't trust something in the chain. It doesn't reliably give an error, but when it does, it's this: "self signed certificate in certificate chain".

This seems like it's an OpenSSL error, but I don't have enough familiarity with OpenSSL to know how to trust the certificate?

Comment: It is not an error, it is a feature. Self-signed certificates are not to be trusted. This can be overridden in the code by adding as (risky) choice that the user can accept self-signed certificates.

Comment: I'm behind a proxy. I don't have much choice but to accept whatever it's serving up.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/faq#_proxy-server-support says in this case set "http.proxyStrictSSL": false -- did you do that?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Yes. I get the same error.

Comment: I tried the "http.proxyStrictSSL" just today and it worked for me.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085's answer is correct for me today as well.

Comment: @adlag No, if it was signed by my organization, there should be a trust store I can add that root cert to. You are thinking of disabling certificate validation entirely ("http.proxyStrictSSL"), which is risky (it shouldn't be done at all, and certainly not permanently), as described below.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a terrible answer (not very secure), but appears to be the current Microsoft official answer. Use `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` in your settings.json file.

This should work to get around the issue of installing extensions inside a corporate network, but I'd recommend disabling the setting if you are going to be working from home/coffee shop and not connected to the corporate VPN.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3492

Comment: It might be a terrible answer, but due to the way corporate proxies often work, it is the correct answer.

Comment: Still this error - request to https://api-v2v3search-0.nuget.org/autocomplete?q=system.data&prerelease=true&take=100 failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: @Saurabh Is this error coming from Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Nuget packages typically don't have anything to do with VS Code which is what we are discussing here.

Comment: @dragon788 i am using VS code insider , and this error come when i try to add any reference like System.Data

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me for the extension "JIRA plugin" (when I try to connect to JIRA, it throws this error). Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This worked a while ago but has recently stopped working for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: Although not the answer for me, this did help me spot that I had an outdated proxy in my settings.json. Worth checking if you're still getting problems.

Comment: Worth noting that if you connect to a remote vscode server, then you should change this setting in the remote `settings.json`.

Comment: thanks! I've struggled for a long time in my company proxy. the setting helps me to sign in github copilot ! some third-party plugins which needs sign in also works!

Answer (score 34):

I was having the same issue, not when installing an extension, but when a certain extension was trying to download data. Adding `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` to my settings file did not work. Disabling SSL is also a really bad idea.

The resolution was to install the Visual Studio Code [win-ca plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca) which makes trusted Windows certificates available to extensions.

Comment: I would heartily recommend everyone test this plugin as this is a FAR better way to do it than essentially disabling SSL for all extensions!!!

Comment: "http.proxyStrictSSL": false Didn't work for me as well, but this Plugin, saved the day! Thankx

Comment: Changing the win-ca plugin default "Win-ca Inject" from "replace" to "append" worked for me.

Comment: Anything like this for Linux? I'm in the same boat and toggling that strictSSL option doesn't help.

Comment: Something for Mac?

Comment: There is a VS Code extension "Mac CA VSCode" which claims to do the same thing

Comment: "Mac CA VSCode" worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

There is actually a better way:

Since VS Code is built on Chromium the ["proxy settings should be picked up automatically"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network) from Google Chrome/Chromium. So if you add your self-signed certificate in Chrome/Chromium by going to:

1. `chrome://settings/privacy`
2. Manage certificates
3. Authorities / Import
4. Select and import your certificate (pem-file)
5. Restart VS Code

I was able to download VS Code extensions despite being behind a corporate proxy.

Remark: Ubuntu 18.04 and VS Code works only with Chrome and not Chromium.

Comment: This worked for me using VS Code under Ubuntu 18.04 two years ago. Now I'm setting up a new PC as well with Ubuntu and it doesn't work anymore. When I'm using the following command I can install extensions in VS Code: `code --ignore-certificate-errors`. In Chromium I'm able to browse the web after adding the CA certificate, but not in VS Code. Any idea?

Comment: It works if install Google Chrome but not with Chromium.

Comment: That is strange. I am using Chromium on PopOS 20.04 which is similar to ubuntu 20.04 and it works. If you try to install an extension in VS Code, what error do you see in the developer console?

Comment: I'm getting a `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. As soon as I install Chrome and add the proxy CA certificate it works.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT**: Still works in 2021 on Big Sur and Catalina, maybe others

First, make sure that the certificates are installed and trusted (I have them in the System category).

Then, go into VScode settings, Application, Proxy, and UNCHECK the "System certificates" option. Restart vscode and RE-CHECK it. Restart again, and it works.

No idea why you have to do this, but it worked for me. I was very surprised. The error I was getting in the developer console (Help - toggle developer tools - console tab) was "self signed certificate in certificate chain".

Answer (score 4):

I had to [add the corporate certificate as a root CA to my local NSS store](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/docs/linux/cert_management.md#add-a-certificate) to get this to work.

```sh
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <certificate nickname> -i <certificate filename>
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96247) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue inside WSL2 (Ubuntu). For me, the solution was to add a new environment variable to `/etc/environment`called `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` and add my proxy's certificate to it. This will fix the problem for all Node instances that respect this variable, not just VS Code and/or Electron, which is exactly what I need.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_extra_ca_certsfile

Comment: This works. Must set this up on the host you are running remote server on.

Comment: P.S. you'll need to disconnect vscode from your host and reconnect to pickup the new variable.

Answer (score 3):

`win-ca` plugin did work for me in Windows (to fix Github Copilot) until I moved to WSL. For WSL:

- Get the cert from IT (you can also export it from any external site from your browser)
- (Optional?) Insert the cert into your system CA store (System dependent: cygwin, WSL, ubuntu, MacOS all different, search for instructions specific to your system)
- Install this VSCODE extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pharndt.node-extra-ca-certs-vscode
- set the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable to point to the your company cert, or the CA store that you inserted the cert into
- restart Vscode

In my case: WSL on windows to get Github Copilot to work I edited the file in the WSL container (after inserting the cert into CA with Ubuntu specific instructions, using `update-ca-certificates`). This files is WSL/guest-side not on your host windows machine:

```
# ~/.vscode-server/server-env-setup
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps, which helped me to resolve similar issue:

1. Open a corporate portal home page in browser and download Root CA certificate. This certificate is usually the first one in the hierarchy of 3 certificates available there. Another option is to ask security team to provide you a corporate Root CA certificate file in Base-64 format.
2. Right-click the certificate file and select Install Certificate.
3. Add Windows Environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS with path to this certificate file.
4. Restart Visual Studio Code and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I finally have found a solution that works with VS Code for those who still run into issues using win-ca.

For those who use things including GitHub Copilot have a odd reason of not respecting NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS system variable and therefore need a little bit more work.

If you already have a .pem file ignore this step and move forward.

Go to your choice of browser and go to: github.com
Exporting the certificate as a Base64-encoded ASCII, certificate chain and making sure the extension of the file ends with .pem

Then, setting NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS variable into user variable (If set as a System Var will not work) with your included .pem file.

After adding the user variable, go to your VS Code installation and finding the Github Copilot extension folder and then going under the /dist directory.

Open `extension.js` file in a code editor and add this code to the top of the extensions file.

```
const tls = require("tls");
const fs = require("fs");

const origCreateSecureContext = tls.createSecureContext;

tls.createSecureContext = options => {
  const context = origCreateSecureContext(options);

  const pem = fs
    .readFileSync(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS, { encoding: "ascii" })
    .replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

  console.log(pem);

  const certs = pem.match(/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n[\s\S]+?\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g);

  if (!certs) {
    throw new Error(`Could not parse certificate ${process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS}`);
  }

  certs.forEach(cert => {
    context.context.addCACert(cert.trim());
  });

  return context;
};
```

This forces Github Copilot to add self signed certificates and lets it work under proxies and Corporate networks.

Answer (score 1):

`"http.proxyStrictSSL": false`  is a horrible answer if you care about security.

Assuming your corporate self signed cert is trusted by your OS, you can now configure VS Code to use the OS cert.  Launch VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings > Search for "certificates" and check the box for  `Http > Experimental: System Certificates V2` "x Controls whether experimental loading of CA certificates from the OS should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue above when opening a proxy tool like Charles. The error disappeared after closing that proxy tool.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the best option, but I had to add certificate to Java cacerts.