# Is there a way to modify the VSCode certificate store to add certificates?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate, pki

Currently, the only way to use VSCode get around a corporate firewall that requires company CA certificates is to set "http.proxyStrictSSL = false" in the config. This is a no-go for me at work. I know that VSCode uses the Chromium networking stack, so there is a way to modify the certificate store when building VSCode (as stated here: [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate), for example)?

Comment: You may be able to find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506539/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-trust-our-self-signed-proxy-certificate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network, the solution is to edit the system certificate store:

> Since Chromium uses the OS's certificate trust infrastructure, the preferred option is to add your proxy's certificate to your OS's trust chain.

This means that your answer is OS-dependent:

- Windows: Powershell [`Import-Certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) or the GUI equivalent
- Mac: Via [Keychain Access](https://support.untangle.com/hc/en-us/articles/212220648-Manually-installing-root-certificate-on-Mac-OSX)
- NSS under linux - it is unclear *which* NSS database it uses. `certutil` is used to edit them.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do remember seeing something like this about 2 years ago. Since I don't have to deal with a corporate firewall anymore it might require me to test it with mitmproxy or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot on Ubuntu 22.04, I found the following steps on this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/cert_management.md#linux-cert-management

Basically you have to:

```
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <certificate nickname> \
-i <certificate filename>
```

The certificate should be in pem format. Flags are specified after nssdb in this order: SSL, email, object signing.

Attention to the flags passed after nssdb, adjust for what you want to do:

-A: Add an existing certificate to a certificate database.

-t: trustargs where:

"C,,": trust as CA (SSL)

To list already installed certificates:

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with VS Code 1.85.1