# Getting a Certificate error when making a GET request in a VS Code extension webview

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a VS Code extension with a webview that contains a React application. In the React code, I'm making a GET request to a REST API, but it keeps failing due to the following error:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Any ideas on why this may be happening or a workaround? Maybe this is a restriction of webviews?

If I make the call in the extension code, it works fine.

Comment: Is the server & domain you're making the request to one you control?  If so, I would check the validity of the certificate.

Comment: See as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506539/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-trust-our-self-signed-proxy-certificate

Answer (score 2):

I upgrade the version of my browser to the latest and it worked me.
find this below given link to know how to update browser version.
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001388.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you get this error about the certificate of the remote side (the one serving the REST API), you get this error because of one of the following:

- the authority that signed the certificate is not recognized on the client side (ie : the authority is not installed on your PC)
- the certificate has expired
- your PC has a wrong date

You can correct the above, or as a workaround you can (depending on your tools) explicitly ignore the untrusted remote certificate. But this workaround should remain for test purpose only, as it is a security breach.