# VSCode gets SSL error when connecting to GitHub

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, firewall

I'm behind our corporate firewall.

I'm trying to push to my GitHub from VSCode 1.41.1. The following error occurs:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myname/myprojectname.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

My project is public, but it's empty right now. I'm trying to push to it to populate it.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42209975/751484), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55191955/751484). Neither worked.

Any other suggestions to try? I appreciate any help.