# VS Code use Jupyter Notebook behind proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, proxy, jupyter-notebook

I referred to this question but I have a different question

- [Get VS Code Python extension to connect to Jupyter running on remote AWS EMR master node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61282651/799593)

**Environment:**

1. The Jupyter Notebook is on AWS EMR.
2. To access notebook from the browser using a SOCKS5 proxy. To do so, I have to connect to the VPN to work, SSH using PuTTY using `.ppk` file and Tunnel (Dynamic Port Forwarding).
3. To automate the step above, I am using PLink([Homepage](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) | [Docs](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) | [Download](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)) : `c:\stuff\plink.exe --ssh -i c:\stuff\file.ppk -D XXXX user-name@<some_IP_address`
4. I can successfully enable proxy by using `msedge.exe --proxy-server="socks5://<address>"` or `chrome.exe --proxy-server="socks5://<address>"`
5. VS Code Version:

```
C:\Users\ablaze>code --version
1.55.2
3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
x64
```

**Objective:**

- How can I access the remote Jupyter Notebook hosted on AWS EMR behind a proxy from Visual Studio Code?

**I tried and failed:**

- Given Visual Studio Code is built on top of Electron and benefits from all the networking stack capabilities of Chromium.
- I used Plink like above to SSH and then executed the following command on my windows command prompt: `C:\Users\ablaze>code --proxy-server="socks5://<address>" --verbose`

Error message:

```
[17668:0505/104410.116:WARNING:dns_config_service_win.cc(692)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
[main 2021-05-05T14:44:10.224Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2021-05-05T14:44:10.224Z] from: c:\Users\ablaze\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app
[main 2021-05-05T14:44:10.224Z] args: {
 _: [],

 ...

 'no-proxy-server': false,
 'proxy-server': 'socks5://localhost:8088',

  ...

  logsPath: 'C:\\Users\\ablaze\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\logs\\20210505T104410'
}

...

[main 2021-05-05T14:44:10.258Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    backupPath: 'C:\\Users\\ablaze\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\Backups\\1620224957079',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  }
]
```

To double check I also opened the log file `C:\Users\ablaze\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20210505T104410\main.log`

```
... 

[2021-05-05 10:44:40.345] [main] [trace] update#checkForUpdates, state =  idle
[2021-05-05 10:44:40.345] [main] [info] update#setState checking for updates
[2021-05-05 10:44:40.345] [main] [trace] RequestService#request https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/update/win32-x64-user/stable/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
[2021-05-05 10:44:40.346] [main] [trace] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (Windows)
[2021-05-05 10:44:44.354] [main] [error] Error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:109:6508)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:315:20)
[2021-05-05 10:44:44.354] [main] [info] update#setState idle
```

Comment: Not sure if I found anything here: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Amicrosoft+vscode+socks5&type=issues

Comment: Are you trying to open an .ipynb file located on a remote host, or trying to connect to a running Jupyter server while running VS Code locally? If you're trying to do the former, the VS Code Remote-SSH extension may be what you need: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks#_proxycommand.

Comment: @joyceerhl the latter. Not sure if the former would help. Trying open a Jupyter notebook from AWS EMR, at the end of the day.

Comment: This is the Jupyter extension's remote server support right now: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server If you've followed those directions and still can't connect, please file an enhancement request on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues.