# How do I install a third-party certificate to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, certificate

I'm trying to install the certificate from cert.techloq.com to visual studio. I've tried researching different ways but nothing is helping me.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Why you need to install certificate on visual studio?

Comment: I installed a filter that creates its own certificates on safe sites. Apparently it's not happening on visual studio, when doing an API request call, so the company told me to install the certificate as a third party certificate to visual studio.

Comment: Did you try installing the certificate on in the local computer certificate store?

Comment: I don't want to do that. I only want to install it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Most Windows applications (unless not Windows native such as Firefox) rely on the standard certificate stores provided by Windows to store certificates. Thus, in your case, ask that company which store you should install the certificate to, and then follow those mandatory steps. There is nothing called "install certificates to Visual Studio".

Comment: Which store is mainly used for Windows' certificates?

Comment: I found a similar question on stack overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506539/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-trust-our-self-signed-proxy-certificate
I'm bringing this up because there are similar solutions but what I am trying to do is to install a new certificate from my proxy server, like the user in the other post (who did not get a solution)

Comment: Local Computer store is used on Windows for certificates... If you already don't know how to do it, you can read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/install-imported-certificates)