# Visual Studio Code devcontainers: how to trust our self-signed proxy/firewall certificate?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssl, firewall

My corporate firewall is breaking TLS/SSL connections. I'd like to add a root certifiate to VSCode trust store. Is it possible?

Not of the below settings seem to affect devcontainers HTTP connections:

```
"http.experimental.systemCertificatesV2": false
"http.systemCertificates": false
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

**.devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1": {
           "installMaven": "true"
       }
     },

    "name": "Java",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/java:1-21-bullseye"
}
```

**Error:**

```
Resolving Feature dependencies for 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1'...
* Processing feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1553:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:970:8)
    at TLSWrap.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:746:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506539/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-trust-our-self-signed-proxy-certificate ? The question is some years old but newer answered accumulated over the years.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes, none of that seems to work specifically when installing the "features". All of the "fixes" seems to deal mostly with the devcontainer image download itself, not the features. So: disabling proxy.strictSSL , adding the corporate firewall to chrome's trust store, setting npm extra certs. None of these seems to affect the "feature installation".